# Audio device initialization fails in Raylib

Tags: c, ubuntu, audio, raylib

I've been trying to get started with raylib. I've installed the necessary libraries and the [Basic Example](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib#basic-example) works. But when I try to run the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "raylib.h"

int main() {
    InitAudioDevice();
    return 0;
}
```

(Compile Command: `cc -o music_freq main.c -lraylib -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lX11`)

I get the following error:
`WARNING: AUDIO: Failed to initialize playback device`

I am on Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, *per se*, but as the log indicates, a **warning**. Simply put, your code at present does not produce a `Window`, and merely initialises an `AudioDevice`. A minimal reproducible example of a functioning window with both `Sound` and `Music` (raylib considers these distinct) is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233503/5414155).

Essentially, create the window, on the main loop (`while (!WindowShouldClose())`) invoke `UpdateMusicStream(music)` and, given the variables have been properly instantiated, music will play whilst the window is open.

Comment: No music plays since audio device cannot be initialized, rest of the code works fine. Pastebin of the output: https://pastebin.com/k8wtdx1A

Comment: @Theorist Can you provide a pastebin of your code? It seems you may not have closed the audio device or stopped the music stream.

Comment: I'm using the code that you have linked to in your answer

Comment: Hi @Theorist, apologies for the long delay. I assume you found a solution, but for anyone else; if the code was copied exactly, please ensure that the file names are in the correct directory, and named exactly as per the example. Otherwise the file should work as intended.