# How to play raw audio with raylib

Tags: c, audio, raylib

I'm trying to figure out the raylib `AudioStream` API, and cannot even generate white noise. I get a short burst of noise (maybe 100ms), but then it's silent.

There's currently only [one official example](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/examples/audio/audio_raw_stream.c) for generating audio using raylib (and a few that do playback), and I cannot find any other documentation on the `AudioStream` API.

I wrote a minimal C program that *should* simply output white noise while displaying static text on the screen. It 'works' for a fraction of a second, then there's no sound. There are also no error messages from raylib (everything is reported as successful).

I'm using 32-bit integer samples, mono, at 48KHz. I'd prefer to use floats, but [the official example](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/examples/audio/audio_raw_stream.c) uses ints (`short`), so I went with that for now.

This is the code:

```c
/* ====================================================================
WARNING: LOWER YOUR SPEAKERS - THEY WILL POP WHEN THIS PROGRAM EXECUTES
=======================================================================
*/

#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>  // required for `rand` and `RAND_MAX`

#define U32_MAX 4294967296
#define U31_MAX 2147483648

int randomSample() {

    /* This helper returns a random, signed 32-bit sample. */

    double randomFraction = rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX);

    return randomFraction * U32_MAX - U31_MAX;
}

void generateSamples(void * buffer, unsigned int frames) {

    /* This audio callback fills a mono buffer with white noise. */

    int * samples = (int *)buffer;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < frames; i++) samples[i] = randomSample();
}

int main(void) {

    /* This is a textbook raylib main function. It sets up an audio
    callback, then loops while the window stays open, before tearing
    down the window, audio device, stream etc. */

    InitWindow(800, 480, "playlib");
    InitAudioDevice();

    AudioStream stream = LoadAudioStream(48000, 32, 1);

    SetAudioStreamBufferSizeDefault(1024);
    SetAudioStreamVolume(stream, 1.0f);
    SetAudioStreamCallback(stream, generateSamples);
    PlayAudioStream(stream);
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) { // loop just redraws the same text
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        DrawText("MUSIC SHOULD BE PLAYING!", 245, 150, 20, LIGHTGRAY);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    UnloadAudioStream(stream);
    CloseAudioDevice();
    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

In LLDB, I was able to establish that the callback is being called (repeatedly), samples are being generated, and are written to the buffer. Yet, all I hear is a short pop of noise as the app opens. The text renders without a problem.

I've tried changing the buffer size to obvious powers of two between 256 and 4096, to no effect.

Another thing: When the program launches, all other audio on my laptop gets muted, then unmutes itself when I close the program. It's like raylib cannot share the output device, so it just takes it over exclusively. I'm not sure if that's just how raylib works, but it seems wrong.

This is on an up-to-date M1 Mac.

Comment: `for (unsigned int i; i < frames; i++) samples[i] = randomSample();` undefined behavor. `i` is uninitialized. Also, you specified the sample size to be 32-bit when you created your `AudioStream` with `LoadAudioStream(48000, 32, 1);`, but then you're filling the buffer with `short` values, which are only 16-bit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to C (obviously). I changed the types from `short` to `int`, and the loop variable initialization to `unsigned int i = 0` inside the loop header. The result was exactly the same. I'll update the code example. Thanks again.

Comment: The example shows the stream being filled (the comment says `Refill audio stream if required`), but your code has no call to `IsAudioStreamProcessed(stream)`. Also, in the example, the audio stream is updated within the main loop using the `UpdateAudioStream(stream, writeBuf, MAX_SAMPLES_PER_UPDATE)` function. In your code, there is no such update call, which might prevent the audio from playing continuously.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was assuming the call to `UpdateAudioStream` was only required as they have an effect buffer, while I just want to copy in the requested number of samples inside the callback. If I have to trigger the callback inside the animation loop, then the callback seems redundant, and any realtime audio input would become super latent, as the animation loop is far too infrequent (+16ms).

Comment: I unfortunately don't know enough to know if those differences are exactly the cause of your error; I merely was pointing them out. Hopefully it helps though.

Answer (score 1):

Following from the comments, I am not quite sure what you mean by placing `UpdateMusicStream(music)` in the animation loop. This does not appear to be what is occurring in the example.

Nonetheless, the below is a minimal reproducible example, which plays an audio file so long as the `Window` is open. It additionally, if you wanted this functionality, plays a sound when `MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT` is pressed.

```
#include "raylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    Sound sound;
    Music music;
    int width = 800;
    int height = 450;

    InitWindow(width, height, "title");
    InitAudioDevice();

    sound = LoadSound("sound.wav");
    music = LoadMusicStream("music.mp3");
    PlayMusicStream(music);

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        UpdateMusicStream(music);

        if (IsMouseButtonPressed(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT))
        {
            PlaySound(sound);
        }

        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(GRAY);
            DrawText("MUSIC SHOULD BE PLAYING!", width / 2, height / 2, 20, LIGHTGRAY);
        EndDrawing();
    }
    StopMusicStream(music);

    CloseAudioDevice();

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How often does the while-loop iterate (and call `UpdateMusicStream`)? I was assuming it ran once per animation frame, like `BeginDrawing` etc.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, and will try to adapt this, but I really want to *generate* samples at runtime, then render them using `AudioStream`. This example plays back existing files. Thank you, but this doesn't output whitenoise.

Comment: @CarlYounger To answer your first question; `WindowShouldClose()` is [checked each frame](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/rcore.c). For your second comment, would `UpdateSound` be useful? It takes a `const void data*` type as one of its arguments. As I understand it, an `AudioStream` is different to (and could be used in conjunction with one of) a `Sound` or `Wave`. So perhaps `UpdateSound` with (in place of where I have `UpdateMusicStream`) `UpdateAudioStream`? You may also find the [raudio.c](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raudio.c) file useful.